# Can I add a wordpress page using the slug for a CPT rewrite

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have a custom post type `rt_services`.  I have rewritten the slug to just services.  I'm not using an archive so I created a page at `/services` and added code for a custom wp_query to call my custom posts.  From there users can click to different services.

Ex Structure.

`/services` - is a page (not set as an archive) with custom WP_Query

`/services/first-service`

`/services/another-service`

This is all working properly.

I was hoping to be able to create a 2nd WordPress page about the packages (not CPT) called advice and place it under the services parent page. I don't want it to show in any of the queries or loops for services which is why I don't want it to be an actual service CPT.  However its URL structure would be:

`/services/service-advice`

I don't have a CPT called Service Advice (service-advice).

However I think WorpdPress is looking for it because when I click that link (or from the page edit screen if I click Preview page) it brings me to the 404 page instead.  I did confirm that the page slug is correct too.

Is it possible to place a page as a child to a reserved re-write like this?

Comment: you cant do that, anything with `/services` based url would have a query related to that `rt_services` post type you created. you can however create a custom rewrite rule for the url structure and point to a specific page

Comment: You could make `service advice` one of your custom post type items and set a custom field to use as a `meta_query` exclusion in your custom `WP_Query` call. It will work easily without needing to mess around with rewrites.